# Squash master now need to merge another branch

Tags: git

I have two git branches, `master` and `dev` for a project. Yesterday I was learning how to use `git rebase` to interactive squash commits. I squashed my `master` branch and it now only contains only a few commits. Today I worked on my `dev` branch (I branched prior to squashing `master`) and made a number of commits on this `dev` branch. Now, I would like to merge my `dev` branch back into my squashed `master`. It was foolish of me, but I realize this was the wrong thing to do.

How can I now merge my `dev` branch into a squashed `master`? Is there any way to to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just `git merge master`? Is it because you don't want to reintroduce the commit you squashed?

Comment: What's preventing you from doing this?  Was dev branched from a commit that no longer exists?  You should be able to `git checkout master ; git merge dev` if that's what you really want to do.

Comment: I tried to do what @gturri/@PaulHicks suggested. However, I get a huge number of merge conflicts. Is there anyway to merge dev into master, but keep all the dev changes so there are no merge conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the commit you branched `dev` off of `master` was affected by the squash, otherwise there shouldn't be any "unnatural" merge conflicts.

There are two ways I can think of to do what you want without actually dealing with those merge conflicts:

1. Undo the squashing you did on `master`.  The pre-squash state of `master` is most likely still in your repository - use `git reflog` to find it and `git reset` to reset `master` to it.  If you made additional commits on `master` after the squash, you can get them onto your restored `master` with `git cherry-pick`.  This option might not be viable if you have already pushed the squashed `master` and other people are using it.
2. `git cherry-pick` the additional commits you did on `dev` onto `master`, then delete the unmergeable `dev` branch.  This option might not be viable if you have already pushed `dev` and other people are using it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried to cherry pick with, `git cherry-pick`, but I get an error: `could not apply 902217c`, `hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths...`. Do you have any idea how I can resolve this?